# Concrete example of RAML 1.0 Example DataType

Tags: design-patterns, types, mule4, anypoint-platform, raml-1.0

I didn't found any suitable example where Example is being used as DataType properly inside main RAML file. Mostly it's being used as .json/.xml file. Is there any proper detail or reference where I could find that. Using AnyPoint Platform design center to build RAML.

Below pasting screenshot of selection point where we can select Example as DataType.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean having a Data type of type example?

Comment: Or how to use an example inside a DataType definition?

Comment: @aled I meant DataType of example ( normally I try with Json and Xml but I want a way to define it like proper example dataType. as mentioned here.
file:///var/folders/y5/9zqmn74j5dzdz3g7_b569gb00000gp/T/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_screencaptureui_ealFNK/Screenshot%202021-09-27%20at%2012.13.35%20AM.png

Comment: I don't think you can attach a screenshot to comments, and it is a bad practice to use screenshots for source code, in stack overflow. The right way is to edit your question and add the snippets as text.

Comment: @aled yes right. Actually I tried to paste link in comment but It didn't work. Now I have pasted screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a page dedicated to ways of defining examples in the documentation ([Guide to Defining Examples in RAML 1.0](https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-named-examples)). I guess that what are asking for is a sample of how to use NamedExample:

api.raml:

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0
title: test
types:
  A:
    properties:
      givenName: string
      familyName: string
    examples: !include fragment.raml
```

fragment.raml:

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0 NamedExample
fullName:
  givenName: ”Chiaki”
  familyName: "Mukai"

otherFullName:
  givenName: "Kyung-won"
  familyName: "Park"
```

I recommend to also read the page [Common Problems Found in RAML 1.0 API Specifications](https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-common-problems-raml-10) that also describes some common mistakes when trying to use examples incorrectly and how to solve them.